# Regular expression to find string which is not part of bigger subscript

Tags: javascript, regex, intellij-idea

I have a very big file with text and want to find:

1. all occurrences of string `selectedRow` which are not:
2. part of `selectedRowIds`
3. are proceeded by `props.`

I am interested in line numbers where all of these conditions are met.

Is is possible to achieve with RegExp?

So e.g. for test data:

```
this.state.selectedRow
this.props.selectedRow
selectedRowIds
```

it will match only first line.

Comment: Rule 3 could be just *"are preceeded by `props.`"*, since when it is `this.props.`, that is already the case.

Comment: Looking for `(?<!props\.)selectedRow(?!Ids)`?

Comment: What about `\b/props\.selectedRow\b`? The `\b` will prevent that there are letters or numbers after `Row`

Comment: this works! thank you @trincot. will read more about lookaheads and lookbehinds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use look around to exclude matches with particular prefix/postfixes:

```
(?<!props\.)selectedRow(?!Ids)
```

Comment: Indeed, it was. Removed